# php multidimensional array flatten only for numeric keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I've been struggling around with a problem which I can't get resolved for hours. I want to have a special designed multidimensional array.

Here is what I have:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => bla
                [form_key] => bla
               )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => bla
                [form_key] => bla
                [extra] => Array
                    (
                        [title_display] => inline
                        [private] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [name] => bla
                [form_key] => bla
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [name] => bla
                [form_key] => bla
                [extra] => Array
                    (
                        [title_display] => inline
                        [private] => 0
                    )

            )

    )

  )
```

But the result should be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
      (
        [name] => bla
        [form_key] => bla
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => bla
        [form_key] => bla
        [extra] => Array
           (
             [title_display] => inline
             [private] => 0
           )
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [name] => bla
        [form_key] => bla
        [extra] => Array
            (
                [title_display] => inline
                [private] => 0
            )

    )
    .
    .
    .
```

So in words:
I want to get rid of the very first array and receiving an incrementing key preserving the associative keys in the subarrays.

I'm trying to use array_values and array_walk_recursive but it seems that I don't have enough experience with php.

Comment: protip: it would be helpful if you `serialize` your array and post that here, so it would be easier for people to `unserialize` it and work with it instead of having to build the array structure manually

Comment: This question is not clear.  Why is it that `[0][0]` becomes [0], `[0][1]` becomes `[1]`, `[1][0]` **disappears**, and `[1][1]` becomes `[2]`?  Please edit your question to clarify you expected result so that future SO readers can understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $items) {
    $newArray = array_merge($newArray, $items);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but at face value...

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($array as $arr) {
  $newArray = array_merge($newArray,$arr);
}
```

Comment: Funny. Completely the same answers. This question probably couldn't be solved any other way.

Comment: @matewka but mine is better because I went with `$arr` like a pirate :P